# Is normal 50% CPU usage while I am running an AR game?

Tags: ios, swift, cpu-usage, arkit

Is normal 50% CPU usage while I am running an AR application? I have tried look to [ARKit documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/arkit).

Comment: If you want to know what's using your CPU, use Instruments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as long as you're checking to make sure viewcontrollers, views, and other objects are deallocating when you mean to remove them from memory, then yes, you're fine. the system will manage this for you.

Answer (score 0):

If you create a brand new Xcode project with `Augmented Reality App` template and these settings:

- Storyboard
- Swift
- SpriteKit

Then run the app, you'll see that the CPU is about 50% - 60% as long as the AR app is running, so I'd say this is normal/expected.